# When i try to install Delphi-OpenCV. I get "%1 is not a valid Win32 application. "

Tags: delphi, opencv, delphi-xe8

When I try to install Delphi-OpenCV. I get this error:

> Can't load package
>   C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\Bpl\dclCommonOpenCV220.bpl.
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I am running: 
 
Win7 64Bit 
Delphi XE8 
 
OpenCV 2.4.11

Does someone know this error?
I have installed all 32Bit and 64Bit DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual C++ DLLs have been wrong.

I recopied the files: msvcp120.dll, msvcr120.dll, msvcp120d.dll, msvcr120d.dll 
from "Delphi-OpenCV\redist\VC2013x86\" to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".

After that everthing is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had horrible trouble installing `OpenCV-Delphi` on `Windows Server 2019`.
I solved it by copying all the files on `C:\OpenCV\build\x86\vc14\bin` both `c:\windows\system32` and `c:\windows\sysWOW64`.
There may be more issue to it, however, this was the moment my application made in `delphi-penCV` starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dll dependency problem.

While developers don't separate those packages into Runtime and DesignTime, problems will continue for those who need to build 32 and 64 versions of their software.

Its very annoying and dificulte to make 32 bit and 64 bit for our applications, even install into 64 bit its impossible, this is a big problem into this project.

**Looks like this project is abandoned.**

I advise you to put all dlls in a single directory, check if all dependencies are correct, and then copy everything to system32 and syswow64, preferably only 32 bit dlls.

Resuming:

Just extract this:

https://mega.nz/#!6ExgTKQJ!fECwuDTRc0Sx8vwY3bbnR7AqFKHQV77E8ZxyqfFgYnk

Into your delphi bpl folder, and now you be able to install the component, forget 64 bit. Don't forget to put it in your final application directory too.